# Is there any way to achieve the one-to-many translation task of flame images ？

Tags: conv-neural-network

The texture characteristics of fire are mainly manifested in edges and colors. I want to control it to generate different colors on the same edge, or generate different edges under the same color. It is difficult to achieve one-to-many translation tasks. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkITo.png)

Comment: This is quite unclear. What are you trying to do in what toolchain, for what platform, and what does image processing have to do with CAN bus?

Comment: Thank you! I'am trying in GAN for flame images translation and flame images augmentation.